# Inability to Halt/Reboot/Shutdown

Tags: arch-linux, grub, bios, uefi

I recently installed a new linux distro on an ASUS laptop that has had its disks wiped clean beforehand. I'm using an EFI partion as my boot partition. Given I'm no expert I've been fiddling around a bit and the result is the halting sequence doesn't even start.

What I experience can be easily described in words:

1. key in any halting command (reboot/shutdown/...)
2. press enter
3. the screen goes blank save for a blinking cursor.
4. stays that way for all eternity

The only way to shutdown is by holding the power button.

This was also on the live cd while I was installing the OS, however the cd actually starts the halting sequence stopping all processes but hangs in the end.

When starting up and arriving at the grub menu, hitting the power button actually turns the pc off.

OS: Arch 230 (Jun 2016)
PC: ASUS

I've redownload and reburned the iso and reformatted my partions many times, but this behaviour persists.

Edit: Tried with Ubuntu live cd and was able to reboot the ASUS.

Edit: I can shutdown my older Samsung laptop with the live arch cd. This suggests the issue is at vendor level firmware difference (maybe).

Edit: The following is a picture of where the live arch cd hangs on the ASUS.

[image: Arch live cd hanging]

Comment: Surely the system is new enough to support ACPI... right?

Comment: I've come across the term while searching for a solution on a forum.

Comment: but I haven't gotten to know how that helps

Comment: [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) is the firmware interface by which the OS tells the hardware to physically turn itself off.  If this is a really ancient laptop you're trying to revive, it may not have ACPI support.

Comment: It's definitely from this decade at least. However does this suggest it's not calling those procedures to turn the hardware off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I missed out an important detail which seemed to be the core of the problem: The ASUS laptop got a nvidia GTX950m.

I noticed nouveau drivers being initialized and apparently it can handle boot up but not shutdown.

therefore the solution was to add the kernel parameter "nomodeset" before booting it from the live CD.

ps Be sure to download and install the nvidia drivers while setting up the system with the live CD.